# How To Translate a button from one position to other postion android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

[image: How To Translate a button from one position to other postion and back to its original positon like in picture]

How To Translate a button from one position to other postion and back to its original positon like in picture
what to do
i am using object animator  but its not performing my desired task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `move_button.xml` in `anim` folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Then from your `Activity` call this:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_button);
b.startAnimation(anim);
```

P.S. There could be other ways from which you can achieve this rotation

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTranslationX and setTranslationY on the Button.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could create two buttons and make them do same thing by placing them wherever you want and hide the button which is not needed and make it shown when needed.